# Getting "access token is empty" with zoho api

Tags: api, go, zoho

I'm trying to create some monitors in site24x7 with an script we used to use in my work.... I've created the self client in zoho api and follow the documentation of site24x7 about refresh tokens. https://www.site24x7.com/help/api/#authentication

The thing is I need to frist create the refresh token and then export these variables in other to run the script to create this monitors... everything looks good until I run the script... looks like I'm doing something wrong... I'll show an example...

[image]

I'm almost 100% sure that it is not the script because the only thing I need to Edit is something to create the monitor with the name, etc.

Any idea or some one has seeing something similar before?

PD: the script is in go lenguague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the tokens were returned from Zoho successfully.  So the issue  may be in the `main.go` script.  If the `main.go` script mainly sets up and calls an http/api call then you might debug by making that call manually with curl.